# A problem about min-cut on subgraphs

Tags: algorithms, graphs, network-flow

When I was trying to solve a problem, I met another problem like this:

Given a undirected connected graph $G=(V,E)(|V|\le100)$ and some subgraphs of $G$: $G_1,G_2,\cdots,G_n(n\le 32)$, and all $G_i$ is connected and **include all the vertexs in $G$.** We need to cut some edges in $G$ so that **neither** of the subgraphs $G_1,G_2,\cdots,G_n$ is a connected graph. What's the minimum number of edges we need to cut?

I have tried many ways but all failed. Could anyone please give me an algorithm to solve it? :)

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that the general problem is NP-complete?  There might not be a better approach than brute-force. Find a _minimal_ cut in any subgraph and remove it and recurse with budget reduced by the size of a cut.

Comment: What is the context where you encountered this task?  What is the motivation? We require you to credit the original source of all copied material: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73671543/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/154076/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: It's a more general version of a multicut problem, which is NP-hard. I don't see how the additional constraints help.